# Produce ultrasonic sound on an iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, audio

I want to produce ultrasonic sound from an iPhone device.
How can I do that?

Comment: Not going to fly - you aren't going to be able to work around the hardware limitations, unless you consider ultrasonic to be, say 18 kHz, which is only ultrasonic for adult humans over a certain age.

Comment: anti-mosquito app, the 18 kHz isn't enough here?

Comment: 18 kHz will be very annoying to young people, dogs, cats and other animals.

Answer (score 3):

At least the iPhone 4s is rated for 20Hz - 20,000Hz, which means it cannot generate ultrasonic frequencies.

I doubt that any mass-market iOS device will produce ultrasonic frequencies.

http://www.apple.com/iphone/iphone-4/specs.html

Comment: True for pretty much any consumer audio device, not just iOS devices, not just phones.

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fly-and-mosquito-killer/id537160389?mt=8 but how this app works then? Need support

Answer (score 3):

I know of no cellphones with ultrasonic transducers as standard.  The small speaker on most phones may well have some response at ultrasonic frequencies, but the D>A converters and audio amplifiers will not.

You need special hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Create the sound on your computer (http://www.blackcatsystems.com/software/audiotoolbox.html maybe?), store it as a WAV (or any other compatible format) and play it back using the audio playback capabilities on iOS.

**EDIT**

OK, so the phone itself can't do it.

Build some custom hardware that can emit sound waves at frequencies higher than 20,000Hz and then develop an application to utilise the hardware.

Comment: This won't work - the sample rate and anti-aliassing filters on the iPhone (or pretty much any consumer device) do not allow for playback of ultrasonic frequencies.