# Produce unhearably high-frequency sound on an iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, audio

I'd like to produce some kind of very high-frequency sound on my iPhone/iPad devices, but how is it possible to produce ultrasonic sound with a **specific frequency** given in **HZ**?

I found just some outdated information like

- [Produce ultrasonic sound on an iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034346/ios-how-to-produce-ultrasonic-sound)
- https://gist.github.com/hotpaw2/630a466cc830e3d129b9

Also the GitHub rep above is not working with my current device, so my question "How to produce ultrasonic sound with specific frequency (20 kHz) on iOS devices using Swift?"

Comment: 20kHz is not ultrasound. Why do you say that question is outdated? Do you have any reason to believe that Apple has added ultrasonic capability to their phones?

Comment: Can you confirm whether you question is "how do I generate a 20kHz tone?" or "how do I generate an ultrasonic tone?" As Josh notes, 20kHz is not ultrasonic. If you want 20kHz, the linked gist looks plausible. Alternately https://github.com/rnapier/ToneGen.

Comment: If you're trying to go above 20kHz, even if the speaker could handle it (and it's unlikely it can), the sampling frequency of the audio system is 44.1kHz, so the maximum frequency is 22kHz, which is within the range of human hearing (at least broadly; there are many humans who can't hear that range, but many who can).